# Why is the Or Operator not working?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am trying to close every open form as long as it's name does not match specific form names (certain forms should remain open), but it is not working like I think it should and I can't figure out why.

I store the forms in a list using a for each loop and Application.OpenForms (the formatting is not working when I try to paste this code in).

I then use another foreach loop to compare the names of the forms in the list to the names I want to keep open. When the loop reaches frmMain the if statement returns true and the form closes which closes the application.

If I remove the OR part of the if statement so the if statement becomes:
if(form.Name != frmMain)
then it works just fine.

```
            //Close all user dependant forms that might be open.
            foreach (Form form in forms)
            {
                if(form.Name != "frmMain" || form.Name != "frmDice")
                {
                    form.Close();
                }
            }
```

Why does the code not work with the OR in the if statement?

Comment: The if condition is always true, I suppose you meant &&.

Comment: Because your test will always be satisfied, it always won't equal at least one of them. Maybe you wanted to use AND?

Comment: Single step debugging, check locals will show logic error

Answer (score 3):

Because you need to use `&&`, not `||`.
If a form is named `"frmMain"` it can't be also named `"frmDice"` -
so for `"frmMain"`, the `form.Name != "frmDice"` part of the condition will return `true`, and of course, this is the same when the form is named `"frmDice"` - the `form.Name != "frmMain"` part of the condition will return `true`.

This means all forms will be closed with the condition you currently have.

Change your condition to `if(form.Name != "frmMain" && form.Name != "frmDice")`.

Of course, it can also be expresses as `if(!(form.Name == "frmMain" || form.Name == "frmDice"))`, but personally I find that less readable.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you explaining it to me as well. It has been a while since I've actually done any coding so I would not have been able to figure it out even though it was a simple mistake :D

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You condition will always resolve to true. For it not to be true the name should be both "frmMain" and "frmDice" at the same time, which is not possible. I think what you want is 
`!( form.Name == "frmMain" || form.Name == "frmDice" )`
Or, alternatively,
`( form.Name != "frmMain" && form.Name != "frmDice" )`

Comment: Ha! I was in the middle of editing that option to my answer when yours popped up... +1 for having the same idea as me 20 seconds faster :-)